# R scale function for new inputs

Tags: r, scale

I am training a neural network model in R. I have scaled my inputs in the training data set using the `scale()` function. However, I do not know how to use this function to transform new inputs to the model. Is there some parameter/formula that can be extracted from the use of the scale function?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is very vague. I would be concerned that it could be closed or downvoted if you don't include a motivating example of what you mean. Are you asking how to transform new data so that has the same transformation applied as the original data? If so, it's `(new_data - mean(old_data))/sd(old_data)`

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron yes, that's exactly what I was asking. thank you.

Comment: See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89172/how-to-scale-new-observations-for-making-predictions-when-the-model-was-fitted-w

Comment: The `recipes` package allows you to apply your training scaling to your other data sets: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recipes/vignettes/Simple_Example.html